# Android WebView error for high density screens

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an Android application which uses a WebView to render web page. In css I have set to show everything twice as big for high density screens (like Nexus 7 2013). If I open the web page from the browser, Everything shows as it should. But when I run the app, everything is very small.

Is there any way to determine why the application WebView shows content for lower density screens but browser (Chrome) shows as it should!

Device: Nexus 7 2013

Answer (score 0):

```
   // I used this class and my code is working fime at my side please try this may be it will help you 


    public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
        private WebView webview;
        private static final String TAG = "Main";
        private ProgressDialog progressBar;
        private TextView header_maintext;
        private TextView headeroptiontext;
        private RelativeLayout back;
        private String url_string="http://www.google.com";
        private String header_maintext_string="Your text";  

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
             setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);


            webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview01);
            header_maintext= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_maintext);
            header_maintext.setText(header_maintext_string);

            headeroptiontext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headeroptiontext);
            headeroptiontext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

              back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
              back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(webview.canGoBack() == true)
                        {
                            webview.goBack();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            finish();
                        }
                 }
            });

            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

            progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "My application", "Loading...");

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
                    if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }

                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                    Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
            webview.loadUrl(url_string);


        }
        @Override

        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                switch(keyCode)
                {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webview.canGoBack() == true){
                        webview.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this article should help explain what you need to do: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/pixelperfect

I suspect that the difference between Chrome and WebView boils down to the WebSettings that are being applied to the WebView.